How to get value from select option and show in table and increase row dynamically?
I want to add selected value from dropdown menu and add it in table to increase row number, and when that selected value added in row its name should not shown in selected tag.
<li className="nav-item dropdown-list">
                <Link
                  className="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
                  data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                >
                  Select Service
                </Link>
                <ul className="dropdown-menu">
                  {categories?.map((c) => (
                    <li onClick={() => setSelected(c.name)} key={c._id}>
                      {c.name}
                    </li>
                  ))}
                </ul>
</li>

And this is the table in which value have to be added and number of row have to increase dynamically
<div className="table">
    <table className="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Serial Number</th>
                <th>Name of Service</th>
                <th>Rate of service</th>
                <th>Total amount</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>{1}</td>
                <td>{selected}</td>
                <td>{checked}</td>
                <td>{price}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>


Can you show the whole code for that?

Dear Austrax , Thank you for your reply, actualy ther is dropdown list of service and when I selct one of these it should add in tble row. In selected table field and I want to add selected value multiple times add in multi rows.

I am not sure what does your setSelected function do. Why don't you just modify your array using setCategories to set the category as selected?

Just to add category in array as checkbox of catwgory..because one user can take service of more category and these category I want to add in row.

SetSelected is other option I was trying to add category in row.
